# Moving character to spawn point on scene change

Tags: godot

My node setup for my game is:
[image]

I have a scene called RoomExit (seen in images below as the blue "door paths") and a scene called SpawnPosition (shown by the little crosshairs next to the door paths)

Level1 has a RoomExit on the right
[image]

Level2 has two RoomExits, one on the left of the room and one on the right)
[image: Level2 with a RoomExit on the left and right side]

Level3 has a single RoomExit on the left side (**NOTE same coordinates as the left RoomExit on Level2**)
[image]

When the player exits Level3 via the RoomExit on the left he appears in Level2 on the right-hand side as expected, however it then triggers the RoomExit collision on the LEFT hand side of Level2 which brings me to Level1....

The way my RoomExit works is when collided, I emit a "OnGotoRoom" on a "SignalBus" Singleton along with the room I wish to go to (ex "res://Rooms/TestLevel2.tscn") and the name of the Spawn Point node in that room (ex "Spawn002")

The "Game" node listens on that "OnGotoRoom" signal and

1. Instances the newRoom
2. Finds the GlobalPosition of the spawn object based on the name ("Spawn002")
3. Set's the player's GlobalPosition = spawn.GlobalPosition
4. Adds the newRoom to the "CurrentLevel" node
5. Calls QueueFree on the previous level

   ```
   public void gotoRoom(string roomPath, string spawnPoint){
   // Instance the new room
   var newRoomScene = (PackedScene)ResourceLoader.Load(roomPath);
   Room newRoom = (Room)newRoomScene.Instance();

   //Set the Global Position of the character = Spawn point global position
   PlayableCharacter player = GetNode<Node2D>("Player").GetChild<PlayableCharacter>(0);
   player.GlobalPosition = newRoom.GetNode<Node2D>("PlayerSpawnPoints").GetNode<Node2D>(spawnPoint).GlobalPosition;
   if (this.playerStats.character == "Robot"){
       player.GlobalPosition = new Vector2(player.GlobalPosition.x, player.GlobalPosition.y-32);
   }
   //Add the newRoom to the "CurrentLevel" Node
   GetNode<Node2D>("CurrentLevel").AddChild(newRoom);

   //If there was already a level, Remove that node
   if (GetNode<Node2D>("CurrentLevel").GetChildCount() != 1){
       var current_room = GetNode<Node2D>("CurrentLevel").GetChild<Room>(0);
       current_room.QueueFree();
   }

   //Move the current level to the first index
   GetNode<Node2D>("CurrentLevel").MoveChild(newRoom, 0);
   }
   ```

**My Thoughts**
I think what's going wrong is that when it moves the character from Level3 to Level2, the player's GlobalPosition isn't updated fast enough so he's colliding with the door on the left hand side (that's in the same position as the door he just exited on Level3).

So I briefly see him in Level2 on the right hand side where I want him, but he already collided with the door on the left because his position wasn't updated fast enough...

I verified this by moving the Left hand door on Level2 away and it works as expected.

I tried updating the character's GlobalPosition to `new Vector2(-10000, -10000)` BEFORE I emit the "OnGotoRoom" signal hoping that he'd not hit the door on the transition, but that didn't fix the problem.

I'm stumped on what to try next... any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: My suspicions led me to creating a timer to skip one frame before loading in the new level. This seems to have fixed the problem...

Comment: I don't have much time to answer, but about your comment I can tell you that you don't need a timer to skip one frame. You can yield on the "idle_frame" of the scene tree. Even from C#, using `ToSignal`.